# asian characters not showing properly in php/html

Tags: php

I'm trying to draw a random Japanese character from a string but when I print it it comes out as "?".  Here's the code:

$chars = "あいうえおかきくけたちつてとさしすせそまみむめもら";

print $chars; // <--- WORKS

$ranLetter = $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];

print $ranLetter;  // <--- DOESN'T WORK

I've tried updating both my html/php page with these:

html - 
php - mysql_set_charset("utf8");

I've also checked my php.ini file to see if my default_charset is set to UTF8 and it is.

But nothing works, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use mb safe functions, here is one way:

```
<?php
$chars = "あいうえおかきくけたちつてとさしすせそまみむめもら";


function mbStringToArray ($string) {
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array;
} 
$new_str=mbStringToArray($chars);

echo  $new_str[array_rand($new_str, 1)];
```

working demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/84lcpW

method 2

```
$chars = "あいうえおかきくけたちつてとさしすせそまみむめもら";

$chars = preg_split('//u', $chars, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

//print_r($chars);

echo $chars[array_rand($chars, 1)];
```

working demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FN8CA0

Comment: Hi thanks, that works!  I'd like to know how I can do the same thing with the code that I already have now that I know that I need to use "mb safe" function.  Is there a rand() equivalent that is mb safe?  Thanks again.

Comment: The working demo is not working for me but I can confirm that your code works.

Comment: works for me, could be your browser encoding default

Comment: Thank you very much, working demo still doesn't work for me in either chrome or ie (error message says "this page can't be displayed") but that's okay. 

I'm not familiar with either solutions as they are a lot different from the  original code which does work for normal alphabetical letters, so I'll need to learn more about mb_s* functions and preg_split, thanks again :-)